# Python does not run shell command properly

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, sed

I have following python sript -

```
import os
command = "echo '12345 Tomcat' | sed -n 's/.*\(^.[0-9]*\).*/\1/p'"
os.system(command)
```

It prints ascii zero character - 
[image]

Try running this command in a shell. It should print `12345`.

Why is this?

Comment: Perhaps the backslashes need to be escaped?

Comment: @user000001 Yup. And now I feel silly.

Comment: Also, if the above command is what you are trying to achieve, you might want to consider using the `re` module or the `.split()` method on the string.

Comment: @GertvandenBerg For someone who knows how to write `regex` and use `sed` do you think I won't know that? :) This is a trimmed down version of my command to simply illustrate the point.

Comment: @KshitizSharma which is why it is a comment.. and "if" is at the start ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\1` is an escape sequence (which is what your image actually shows, not `\0`). You want to treat it as the characters `\` and `1`, so prefix your string with `r` to make the string literals "raw":

```
command = r"echo '12345 Tomcat' | sed -n 's/.*\(^.[0-9]*\).*/\1/p'"
```

Comment: Oh... did not know about `r"..."` syntax. From what version onward, is this syntax supported? (Asking because I may have to deal with old python versions (version<=2.4)...)

Comment: @anishsane: The syntax was introduced in Python 1.5: http://www.python.org/download/releases/1.5/whatsnew/

Answer (score 4):

Python is interpreting your backslashes. You can use the "raw" Python string notation instead:

```
command = r"echo '12345 Tomcat' | sed -n 's/.*\(^.[0-9]*\).*/\1/p'"
```

or, escape the backslashes again:

```
command = "echo '12345 Tomcat' | sed -n 's/.*\\(^.[0-9]*\\).*/\\1/p'"
```

Comment: from http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects
7.2.5.8. Raw String Notation